# The last line (line 247) in my ERC-20 code has a "ParserError: Expected Pragma, import directive or contract interface". How do I solve this?

Tags: tokens, erc-20

What measures do I take to solve this? I am currently on Compiler version 0.4.24 and this error shows up multiple times in my code which I solved by inserting a bracket. Now it is at the end of the code and I am not sure what to do. Please help, thanks.

```
{ 
              pragma solidity ^0.4.24;


              contract owned {
              address public owner;

              function owned() public {
              owner = msg.sender;
              }

           modifier onlyOwner {
           require(msg.sender == owner);
                               _;
         }
           function transferOwnership(address newOwner) onlyOwner public {
    owner = newOwner;
}


    interface tokenRecipient { function receiveApproval(address _from, uint256 _value, address _token, bytes _extraData) external; }

   contract TheJEFF {
// Public variables of the token
string public name;
string public symbol; 
uint8 public decimals = 3;
uint256 public totalSupply; 

// This creates an array with all balances
mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;
mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) public allowance;

//This generates a public event on the blockchain that will notify clients
event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
event Approval(address indexed _owner, address indexed _spender, uint256 _value);

//This notifies clients about the amount burnt
event Burn(address indexed from, uint256 value);

/**
 * Constrctor function
 * 
 * Intializes contract with initial supply tokens to the creator of the contract
 * */
 function TheJEFF(
     uint256intialSupply,
     string tokenName,
     string tokenSymbol
) public {
    totalSupply = intialSupply *50000000.000** uint256(3);
    balanceOf [msg.sender] = totalSupply;
    name = "TheJEFF";
    symbol = "GXAU";
}
   /**
   * Internal transfer, only can be called by this contract
 */
function _transfer(address _from, address _to, uint _value) internal {
    // Prevent transfer to 0x0 address. Use burn() instead
    require(_to != 0x0);
    // Check if the sender has enough
    require(balanceOf[_from] >= _value);
    // Check for overflows
    require(balanceOf[_to] + _value > balanceOf[_to]);
    // Save this for an assertion in the future
    uint previousBalances = balanceOf[_from] + balanceOf[_to];
    // Subtract from the sender
    balanceOf[_from] -= _value;
    // Add the same to the recipient
    balanceOf[_to] += _value;
    emit Transfer (_from, _to, _value);
    // Asserts are used to use static analysis to find bugs in your code. They should never fail
    assert(balanceOf[_from] + balanceOf[_to] == previousBalances);
}


/**
 * Transfer tokens
 *
 * Send `_value` tokens to `_to` from your account
 *
 * @param _to The address of the recipient
 * @param _value the amount to send
 */
function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
    _transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
    return true;
}

/**
 * Transfer tokens from other address
 *
 * Send `_value` tokens to `_to` in behalf of `_from`
 *
 * @param _from The address of the sender
 * @param _to The address of the recipient
 * @param _value the amount to send
 */
function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
    require(_value <= allowance[_from][msg.sender]);     // Check allowance
    allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
    _transfer(_from, _to, _value);
    return true;
}

/**
 * Set allowance for other address
 *
 * Allows `_spender` to spend no more than `_value` tokens in your behalf
 *
 * @param _spender The address authorized to spend
 * @param _value the max amount they can spend
 */
function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public
    returns (bool success) {
    allowance[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
    emit Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
    return true;
}

/**
 * Set allowance for other address and notify
 *
 * Allows `_spender` to spend no more than `_value` tokens in your behalf, and then ping the contract about it
 *
 * @param _spender The address authorized to spend
 * @param _value the max amount they can spend
 * @param _extraData some extra information to send to the approved contract
 */
function approveAndCall(address _spender, uint256 _value, bytes _extraData)
    public
    returns (bool success) {
    tokenRecipient spender = tokenRecipient(_spender);
    if (approve(_spender, _value)) {
        spender.receiveApproval(msg.sender, _value, this, _extraData);
        return true;
    }
    }
   /**
 * Destroy tokens
 * Remove value from the system irreversibly
 * 
 */
  function burnFrom(address _from, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) 
 {
    require(balanceOf[_from] >= _value);                // Check if the targeted balance is enough
    require(_value <= allowance[_from][msg.sender]);    // Check allowance
    balanceOf[_from] -= _value;                         // Subtract from the targeted balance
    allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;             // Subtract from the sender's allowance
    totalSupply -= _value;                              // Update totalSupply
    emit Burn(_from, _value);
    return true;
}
}


  contract TheJEFF is owned, TokenERC20 {
    uint256 public sellPrice;
    uint256 public buyPrice;

    mapping (address => bool) public frozenAccount;
     /*This generates a public event on the blockchain that will notify clients*/
      event FrozenFunds(address target, bool frozen);

       /*Initializes contract with initial supply tokens to the creator of the contract */
function TheGoldmoneyToken(
uint256 initialSupply, 
string tokenName,
string tokenSymbol
) TokenERC20(initialSupply, tokenName, tokenSymbol) public{}

/* Internal transfer, only can be called by this contract */
function _transfer(address _from, address_to, uint_value) internal {
    require (_to != 0x0);                       // Prevent transfer to OxO address. Use burn() instead
    require (balanceOf[_from]>= _value);        // Check if sender has enough
    require (balanceOf[_to] + _value >= balanceof[_to]); // Check for overflows
    require(!frozenAccount[_from]);             // Check if sender is frozen
    require(!frozenAccount[_to]);               // Check if recipient is frozen
    balanceOf[_from] -= _value;                 // Subtract from the sender
    balanceOf[_to] += -value;                   // Add the same to the recipient
    emit Transfer (_from, _to, _value);         
   }

     ///Create 'mintedAmount' tokens and send it to 'target'
     ///@param target address to receive tokens
     ///@param mintedAmount the amount of tokens it will receive
     function mintToken(address target, uint256 mintedAmount) onlyOwner public {
balanceOf[target] += mintedAmount;
totalSupply += mintedAmount;
emit Transfer(0, this, mintedAmount);
emit Transfer(this, target, mintedAmount);
     }

      ///@notice 'freeze?' Prevent| Allow 'target' from sending & receiving tokens
      ///@param target Address to be frozen
      ///@param freeze either to freeze it or not

      function freezeAccount(address target, bool freeze) onlyOwner public {
frozenAccount[target] = freeze;
emit FrozenFunds(target, freeze);
    }

     function transfer (address _to, uint256 _value) {
require(!frozenAccount[msg.sender]);
require(approvedAccount[msg.sender]);
      }

        //*Allow token to automatically detect and refill user balance if balance is too low to pay for Ether blockchain transaction cost*//

     uint public minBalanceForAccounts;

    function setMinBalance(uint minimumBalanceInFinney) onlyOwner {
minBalanceForAccounts = minimumBalanceInFinney * 10 finney;
      }

      /*Send coins*/
      //If the sender does not meet minimum requirement, this allows them to be refunded
     function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) {
if(msg.sender.balance < minBalanceForAccounts)
    sell((minBalanceForAccounts - msg.sender.balance)/ sellPrice);
     }

     ///@notice Allow users to buy tokens for 'newBuyPrice' eth and sell tokens for 'newSellPrice' eth
    ///@param newSellPrice Price users can buy from the contract
    ///@param newBuyPrice Price users can buy from the contract
     function setPrices (uint256 newSellPrice, uint256 newBuyPrice) onlyOwner public {
sellPrice = newSellPrice;
buyPrice = newBuyPrice;
     }

     /// @notice Buy tokens from contract by sending ether 
     function buy() payable public {
uint amount = msg.value / buyPrice;                 //calculates the amount
_transfer(this, msg.sender, amount);                //makes the transfers
     }

     ///@notice Sell 'amount' tokens to contract
     ///@param amount of tokens to be sold
     function sell(uint256 amount) public {
address myAddress = this;
require(myAddress.balance >= amount * sellPrice);    //checks if contract has enough ether to buy
_transfer(msg.sender, this, amount);                //makes the transfers
msg.sender.transfer(amount * sellPrice);            //sends ether to the seller
    }
    }

   }
```

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

Comment: The `pragma ...` line shouldn't be enclosed in braces - it should be on the first line in the file. The error is probably just saying _"I've gone all the way through this file and can't find a valid pragma statement."_, which is why it's claiming to be coming from the last line. I haven't looked at the rest of the contract, which is presumably missing a brace somewhere, and which was fixed by adding the brace right at the top, which doesn't work for other reasons. Ensuring everything has the correct indentation should make errors like this easy to spot.

Comment: Okay, I will try. I added a closing bracket to the "contract owned" part, but then the error moved to the line below on line 7 and disappeared from the last line 247. What is the program looking for?

Comment: first correct the indentation and check if you have all the necessary contracts - parent contracts imported from where you have copied the code.

Answer (score 1):

why do you have an opening curly brace before the "pragma solidity ^0.4.24;" line? it's supposed to be the first line in the entire program. So first you delete the first opening curly brace, so your code changes from

```
{ 
              pragma solidity ^0.4.24;


              contract owned {
...
```

to

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;


              contract owned {
...
```

make sure the ENTIRE file starts with the "pragma solidity ^0.4.24;" line, that way the "ParserError: Expected Pragma, import directive or contract interface" error will go away, and then you can see if there are any other issues with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Do format your code with correct indentation.

1)There is an opening brace at the top - start of the code.
2) Your `owned` contract is not closed with closing brace.
3) Multiple contracts with same name - `TheJEFF` 
4) variable not well defined `uint256initialSupply`
 
5) `TokenERC20` not defined

Comment: So, I added the closing brace below the owned contract line, but the error then moves to the line below it " function owned () public { ". What do I do? Is it going to continue moving down?

Comment: it seems you have an extra closing brace at the bottom of the code. try removing that last one. and also have you removed the opening brace at top the code?

Comment: Yes, just did both. The error is still on it...

Comment: yep dont worry you will get more errors. 
 1) Multiple contracts with same name - TheJEFF
 2) variable not well defined uint256initialSupply
 3) TokenERC20 not found
and others.
I suggest you to copy and paste again from your source. and also copy the parent contracts. Dont leave them.